# Multiple service_name and hosts with same alias

Tags: oracle, tnsnames

I am currently working on a duplicated infrastructure like this :

We have two data server, with two database on each.

- Server 1

  - Oracle instance 1
  - Oracle instance mirror 1
- Server 2

  - Oracle instance 2
  - Oracle instance mirror 2

I cannot change the instance name on the database.

```
DWH_connection =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = Server1)(PORT = 1521)
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = Server2)(PORT = 1521)
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = Oracleinstance1)
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
    )
  )
```

Here is what I know we can do, but I am stuck and can't find any docs. Maybe I am bad at searching, but can't find a way.

I would like to get the `Server 1 - Oracle instance 1` with the same alias as `Server 2 - Oracle instance 2`. So in case `Server 1` is not up, our application will go the Server 2. So this is what I would like to have:

```
DWH_connection =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = Server1)(PORT = 1521)
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = Server2)(PORT = 1521)
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = Oracleinstance1)
      (SERVICE_NAME = Oracleinstance2)
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
    )
  )
```

Comment: Stuck with what? What is the problem? Does the above connection string not work for you? You can create services with the same name on both servers. Use `srvctl add service` if you use Oracle Restart, or `DBMS_SERVICE` if you do not have Oracle Restart.

Comment: I edited to show the problem more efficiently. I do not have the right to modify the database server. All I have acess to, is our Oracle client installation. This is why I am looking for a client side solution. Otherwise i'll lose a lot of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need different `DESCRIPTION` sections to have different `SERVICE_NAME` in the `CONNECT_DATA` section.

```
DWH_connection =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (LOAD_BALANCE=OFF)
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = Server1)(PORT = 1521))
      (CONNECT_DATA =
        (SERVICE_NAME = Oracleinstance1)
        (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      )
    )
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = Server2)(PORT = 1521))
      (CONNECT_DATA =
        (SERVICE_NAME = Oracleinstance2)
        (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      )
    )
  )
```

The default value of `LOAD_BALANCE` is `ON`, but in your case, connections should go to the first server, and go to the second one only if that fails, so `LOAD_BALANCE=OFF` is needed, otherwise connections would be distributed between the 2 servers.

Comment: Owh. I didn't got it when I was reading the documentation. Thanks for pointing it out !

Comment: Just 1 small remark. If your `Server1` is down then it will take a longer time to connect since it waits for the timeout on `Server1` before it goes to `Server2`. It can be that a user will complain on that.